# How to write Test Driven Development in .Net core MS Test in VS 2019?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, tdd, mstest

We have been developing REST APIs in .Net core 3.1 and using MS TEST - Test Project in Visual Studio 2019 for unit testing.

Now we have a hard rule to follow ***Test Driven Development***. In theory I can understand that TDD will involve writing tests to implement a requirement and continuously iterate through RED GREEN and REFACTOR cycles.

Now my question is, if I have a endpoint which will **get all books according to author id from DB**, like following endpoint

```
httpget : api/boooks/authors/1006
```

which will return a response, **what all cases/ test methods should I write in the Test class of MSTest project, so that I can say that, I have followed Test Driven Development** ?

Before TDD, I will write a TestMethod for the Service method which will call the Database layer and get the author information from SQL DB. SO only 1 test method with different input to mock, will be written.

I am very new to TDD hence the question. Any comment is helpful

Comment: I agree, but they need it :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're in doubt about how many test cases you need to write, you may consider using [the Devil's Advocate technique](https://blog.ploeh.dk/2019/10/07/devils-advocate) to critique your test code.

If, for example, you write a single unit test (pseudocode):

```
Initialise System Under Test (SUT)
Call api/boooks/authors/1006
Assert that the response is, say, [Foo, Bar]
```

Then, according to [the red-green-refactor checklist](https://blog.ploeh.dk/2019/10/21/a-red-green-refactor-checklist) and the Devil's Advocate technique, the implementation should be the simplest thing that could possibly work. What would that be?

```
return [Foo, Bar];
```

Unconditionally returning a hard-coded value is not the implementation you have in mind. This means that you have *at least* one more test case to write.

Another heuristic to keep in mind is that [there should be at least as many test cases as the cyclomatic complexity](https://blog.ploeh.dk/2019/12/09/put-cyclomatic-complexity-to-good-use) of the implementation, and most likely more.

Comment: Thank you for the response ! Just another question can we follow TDD approach with MS test in Visual Studio 2019 ?

Comment: @AnnSnow I don't see why not, although [I haven't used MSTest since 2010](https://blog.ploeh.dk/2010/04/26/WhyImmigratingfromMSTesttoxUnit.net).

Comment: Please consider that TDD is software development practice and not related to or constrained by any technological factors such as the type of programming language or testing framework.

Answer (score 0):

When I start to write test cases on new code for TDD (not a modification to existing code), I usually start with a glut of typical scenarios:

- One simple test case (happy path with easiest implementation)
- One complex test case (multiple inputs for lists, all values filled in, etc.)
- Edge cases (min/max values for all inputs, within reason)
- Invalid inputs (text instead of numbers in JSON inputs, missing required values, negative integers for indexes, etc.)
- Purposefully forgetting required pre-initialization steps to verify they are caught and appropriate exceptions are thrown
- OBOBs (off-by-one bugs)

All except the last one applies to modified code, unless you are adding a new pre-initialization step. Additionally, I go through the test cases to verify all scenarios are tested. For example, adding a new input to a method overload to perform additional functionality will often need more tests around existing code to make sure the new functionality doesn't alter the pre-existing conditions of the objects.

Also, I always make sure to add test cases when bugs are identified to not only verify the bug is a bug, but to have test cases that will verify the update corrects the issues.